# Android wear 4.3 Vibrate within an app

Tags: android, wear-os, vibration

I was given a project from my professor. He wants me to take an app he built and make it vibrate instead of beep. Can anyone help me with this?

This looks like the part of the code that he uses to make it vibrate:

```
MediaPlayer beepSound;
beepSound = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.beep);

beepSound.start();
```

It would appear the first two commands set up the audio parameters. While the last command tells the watch (samsung galaxy gear) to beep.

For vibration, what do I need to plug in instead?

Answer (score 0):

The MediaPlayer class is only used to handle audio or video, and the given code snippet is used to play the beep sound,

To vibrate you need to use the Vibrator class,

Try:

```
import android.os.Vibrator; ... 
Vibrator v = (Vibrator) this.getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE); 
// Vibrate for 500 milliseconds 
v.vibrate(500);
```

Note:
Don't forget to include permission in AndroidManifest.xml file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! It seems I am getting errors. I am sure it is something silly like I am not putting the code in the right place or something. 

Here is my AndroidManifest.xml file
[AndroidManifest.xml](https://photos.google.com/share/AF1QipPq1RAe5kGlNEKc9o3Wzn9zTfxdnK1Spj62-wepYx3dVfjH6PTDwf6R3WZ_idbq8Q?key=OGM3TWhLdnl0Q3psLXZYZG9wY2lLUXJmWGdDMmxB).

Comment: Here are my errors:
[My error](https://photos.google.com/share/AF1QipNxmYTFz-pI7isMfMoS2mH3cnb-Rm1kZxb7gwJBswDY4QEAZPZm-g83fqvbBQttvQ?key=bFpsWUgwMW1RUkJuQU8zUTh1SG5JdXhIaExTRVN3).

[Import not used cuz of my error](https://photos.google.com/share/AF1QipNne3TAWDxTm0owK7_GpRNXEYbVPjUYBk3F-Jb-zd0i-G7t3XsfNSo7SE_veMpz1Q?key=TC1xeXBvdXBmblFKejZUZDhha0dBZVFIajJYbmhB).


Thanks again for all your help!

Comment: I have edited my code, instead of this.context.. , just use this.getSystemService...  and regarding your manifest errors just check mouse over those errors it ll give you the solution

Comment: thiyagab, I can't THANK YOU ENOUGH for your help! This is for my dissertation. Without this I can't graduate. Your are very kind to help!!!  It has compiled with no errors!! I need to buy a watch to test it but you have certainly helped me make a lot of progress. :)

Comment: I finally got an android phone to compile and debug my changes. It looks like the app crashes. :( Is there anything I can post that would help to diagnosis it? Here is the output from the compiler.

Comment: 04-20 13:55:40.369 2163-2163/readsms.smartwatch.hejibo.info E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                              java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{readsms.smartwatch.hejibo.info/readsms.smartwatch.hejibo.info.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: System services not available to Activities before onCreate()

Comment: ndroid.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1580)
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1674)
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
                                                                                  at